# WCF crm connection failure, due to unsecured string

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, connection-string, wcf-binding, dynamics-crm-online

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Medinet" connectionString ="AuthType=Office365;Url=https://medinetdevsandbox.crm11.dynamics.com; Username=victor@******8;Password=*******"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>  
  <bindings>  
    <wsHttpBinding>  
      <binding name="TransportSecurity">  
        <security mode="Transport">  
             <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />  
         </security>  
      </binding>  
    </wsHttpBinding>  
  </bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My error is:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'An unsecured
>   or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See
>   the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.'
>   FaultException: Authentication Failure.

My .CS file is the below:

```
namespace DemoLibrary
{
    public partial class Nurses : Form
    {
        //private static OrganizationService _orgService;
        //private static IOrganizationService service;
        public Nurses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            service();
            //GetOrgService();
        }

        private void nurseRegistrationBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var orgContext = new MedinetCRMService(GetOrgService());


            var nurse = new new_nurse
            {
                new_FirstName = firstNameTextBox3.Text.ToString(),
                new_Surname = lastNametextBox2.Text.ToString()

            };


            if (GendercomboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                nurse.new_Gender = new OptionSetValue(0);
            }
            else
                nurse.new_Gender = new OptionSetValue(1);

            new_hospital hospital = new new_hospital();
            hospital.new_name = "Birmingham Community Trust";
            Guid hospitalId = (Guid)service().Create(hospital);
            //orgContext.AddObject(hospital);
            //Guid hospitalID = (Guid)hospital.Id;
            CrmEntityReference hospitalReference = new CrmEntityReference(hospital.LogicalName, hospitalId);
            nurse.new_name = hospitalReference.ToString();




            //orgContext.AddObject(nurse);
            //orgContext.SaveChanges();

            service().Create(nurse);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully added a Nurse to CRM");
        }


       // public static OrganizationService GetOrgService()
       // {
            //    if (_orgService == null)
            //    {
            //        CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Medinet"].ConnectionString);
            //        //CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse( "Url=https://medinetdevsandbox.crm11.dynamics.com; Domain=Medinet; Username=; Password=G;");
            //        _orgService = new OrganizationService(connection);
            //    }
            //    return _orgService;

       // }


        public static IOrganizationService service()
        {
            //WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding();
            //b.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
            //b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            //string connString = "Url=https://medinetdevsandbox.crm11.dynamics.com; Domain=Medinet; Username=victor; Password=;";
            CrmConnection connection = new CrmConnection("Medinet");
            IOrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(connection);

            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure my login details are correct. I have been on this for weeks. Someone with more knowledge please help.

Comment: Which version of the CRM assemblies are you using?

Comment: @HenrikH how do I determine this,  am fairly new to CRM development?

Comment: @HenrikH Are talking about these:   using System;
                                                          using System.Collections.Generic;    
                                                           using System.ComponentModel;   
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MedinetCRM;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel;

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of _Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk_. Can you check the version of the DLL (or the nuget package that you installed it from)?

Comment: i solved it. updated the Xrm.sdk via the manage Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

That connection method is deprecated. I would suggest getting the latest [Xrm Tooling](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/) NuGet package.

Then instantiate an instance of [CrmServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.aspx), which implements `IOrganizationService`, and has a lot of additional methods:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Here's [an article](https://crmtipoftheday.com/777/so-long-microsoft-xrm-client-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish/) about the transition from Xrm.Client to CrmServiceClient.